# How to get the site root URL when using Wordpress gutenberg wp object

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks, create-guten-block

I just created my first gutenberg block plugin using the npm package `create-guten-block`.

The edit function looks like the code you see below. But it gives a 404 not found on the `apiFetch()` call because the website lives in a folder, not in the root of the domain. In other words: The structure of the hostname is `http://localhost/websitename/` not `websitename.local`.

```
edit: ( props ) => {
    if ( ! props.attributes.categories ) {
        wp.apiFetch( {
           url: '/wp-json/wp/v2/categories'
        }).then(categories => {
            props.setAttributes( {
                categories: categories
            });
        });
    }
    return (
        true
    );
}
```

So what would be the equivalent to PHP's `get_site_url()`? Is that data somewhere stored in the `wp` object? If so, where? Because I need to prepend `/wp-json/wp/v2/categories` with the right site URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found the solution myself.

In the `init` hook of your Gutenberg block plugin you can have a function that creates a global data object for you to use in the Wordpress editor file `block.js`.

So, in `init.php` inside of the `init` hook you could add:

```
wp_localize_script(
    'custom_block',
    'cs_data',
    [
        'siteUrl'       => get_site_url()
    ]
);
```

This way the global object `cs_data` is available in `block.js`. So the Fetch call could use the dynamic path now like this.

```
wp.apiFetch( {
    url: cs_data.siteUrl + '/wp-json/custom-data/v1/post-types'
} ).then( postTypes => {
    props.setAttributes( {
      postTypes: postTypes
    } );
} );
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

Try updating your `site_url` or `home_url`

`site_url()` will always be the live location where you can reach the site wheras `home_url()` would be where you have set your homepage.

Try setting the `home_url()` to the "*http://localhost/websitename*" by visiting and editing the **General > Settings "WordPress address (URL)"** field.

You could also define the paths programmatically by editing the **wp-config.php**:

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://localhost/websitename/' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://websitename.local' );
```

Then you could use `get_home_url()` to retrieve the correct path.